# How to send multiple parameters in echo based on isset

Tags: php

I have pagination code that is working perfect when filters are not set. However when i use filters on my page it displays every product but unlimited number of pages are shown with nothing on it after products are done. I checked if it would work if i send filter like :

```
if(isset($brand)){
    echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'}}?currentpage=$nextpage&brand=$brand'>></a> "
}else{
    echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'}}?currentpage=$nextpage'>></a> 
}
```

but this is not efficient way to do this because i will have to check for 20 filter. Also I tried with string adding and adding it later to `<a>` but it is not working like:

```
$filters;
if(isset($brand)){
    $filters .= "&brand=".$brand;
}
```

**So my question is**: Is there a way to check in echo if filters are set and send them all to next page(like: brand, color, size..).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `http_build_query` to build an HTTP query string from an array of values. When building your array, use the null coalescing operator to avoid notices about using undefined variables.

```
$filter_array = [
    "currentpage" => $nextpage,
    "brand" => $brand ?? "",
    "color" => $color ?? "",
    "size"  => $size ?? "",
    // and the rest of your variables
];
$query = http_build_query($filter_array);

echo sprintf('<a href="%s?%s">&gt;</a>', $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], $query);
```

---

Or, for old unsupported PHP versions:

```
$filter_array = [
    "currentpage" => $nextpage,
    "brand" => isset($brand) ? $brand : "",
    "color" => isset($color) ? $color : "",
    "size"  => isset($size) ? $size : "",
    // and the rest of your variables
];
$query = http_build_query($filter_array);

echo sprintf('<a href="%s?%s">&gt;</a>', $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], $query);
```

Comment: Oh, I never heard about this what should i put there as it say unexpected ?

Comment: Are you using an old version of PHP? This has been there since 7.0 released three years ago.

Comment: I am using 7.2.8 version

Comment: Then you would not get an error about an unexpected `?`.

Comment: It is working! Thank you man so much, not only did u help me but I learned something great tonight !

Comment: How can i make sprintf in this case `echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$x'>$x</a> "; `

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it

add all the filters into an array first

```
$filters = array();
$filters['brand'] = $brand;
$filters['color'] = $color;
$filters['size'] = $size;
```

loop through the filters array to make params string

```
$anchor_tag_params = "";
foreach($filters as $key => $value)
{
    $anchor_tag_params .= "&".$key."=".$value;
}
```

and then just append the params string to the anchor tag href

```
$anchor_tag_html = '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?currentpage='.$nextpage.$anchor_tag_params.'"></a>';
```